# What is an equivalent of `created()` in the Vue.js composition api?

Tags: vuejs2

Could you advise what is the equivalent of the `created()` in the new Vue composition API, which I'm using from within Vue2 like this:

```
import { reactive, toRefs } from '@vue/composition-api'
```

Answer (score 120, accepted):

From the Composition API docs on [Lifecycle Hooks](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-lifecycle-hooks.html):

> Because `setup` is run around the `beforeCreate` and `created` lifecycle hooks, you do not need to explicitly define them. In other words, any code that would be written inside those hooks should be written directly in the `setup` function.

Anything you would have done in the `created` hook you can do in `setup`.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. Unfortunately vue removed this info from the docs. Wonder why they do this.