# how to use created hook in setup script?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

```
<script>
    export default {
        setup() {

        }
        created() {

        }
    }
</script>
```

When i change to use script setup syntax, how to use created hook ?

```
<setup script>
    // how to use created hook ?
</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an equivalent of \`created()\` in the Vue.js composition api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64897835/what-is-an-equivalent-of-created-in-the-vue-js-composition-api)

Answer (score 2):

As you can see here, there is no such thing as `created` in Composition API lifecycle: https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-lifecycle.html

Because it happens before the actual creation

> All APIs listed on this page must be called synchronously during the setup() phase of a component. See Guide - Lifecycle Hooks for more details.

[image]

`created` hook coming just after as shown here: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html#lifecycle-diagram

Comment: you right, is there a api to register created hook in setup syntax and called in property time?

Comment: @hewc as you can see, there is no such way of doing things. At the same time, as this [comment says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73865083/how-to-use-created-hook-in-setup-script/73865190?noredirect=1#comment130427221_73865083), there is no real need for a `created` one because it will happen before the `mounted` hook anyway. What would be such an usecase that you need `created` specifically? Is it to call an external API or alike?

Comment: i use uni-app which inject onReady, onShow lifecycle hooks, such as beforeEnter beforeLeave hook in vue-router that injected to vue option, so i need to call that, but setup syntax may don't support~~~

Comment: @hewc what are those doing exactly? Seems like they are like regular DOM event listeners. Also, you need to know that even if you use Composition API, you can call the Options API in the same file too, no issues with that.

Answer (score 0):

there no need to use "created" in setup script because there's not "created" hook at all with composition Api in vue3.
You just need to write your code in  block:

```
<script setup> 
    import { onMounted } from "vue";
      
    onMounted(() => {
      console.log('mounted');
    });
    
    console.log("created")
</script>

// output will be:
// created
// mounted
```